# Small datetime input in a <pre> tag is incorrectly displayed on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I am coding an application that displays text inside <pre> tags. Sometimes there will be a datetime input that I styled using css (see below). Unfortunately, it seems that, only on firefox, my css code works poorly when the input is in <pre> tags. In other browsers, like Chrome, this problem does not occur.

How can I fix this problem ?

Here is my code (simplified) :

```html
<body>
    <style>

        input {
            flex-shrink: 1;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: black;
            --tw-border-opacity: 0;
            --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 0.5rem;

            height: 1.5rem/* 24px */;
            padding-left: 0.5rem/* 8px */;
            padding-right: 0.5rem/* 8px */;
            font-size: 0.75rem/* 12px */;
            line-height: 1rem/* 16px */;
            line-height: 1.625;
        }

    </style>
    With pre tag : <br>
    
    <pre><input type="datetime-local"/></pre>
    
    Without pre tag :<br>
    
    <input type="datetime-local"/>
</body>
```

And for people who don't use Firefox, here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGKNj.png)

Edit: I tried with a normal div with the whitespace-pre-wrap property but it don't works too !

Edit 2: Found the solution! Just add the property `white-space: normal;` to the input so that the text centers well.

Comment: How about specifying the height and line height of input, say 40px, that will work in both the browser.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer !
However I would like to keep the current height of the input (24px). Is there any other solution? Firefox seems to be able to display these inputs in small size since it does it when you remove the <pre> tag

Comment: This might be a bug in Firefox itself. Can't think of any other way of solving this, than setting larger height.

Comment: Why would one want to have an input tag inside a pre tag?

Comment: I want to display a formatted JSON and the values must be editable. The pre tag preserves the indentation (and daisyui uses it to add the line-numbers)

Comment: You can answer your own question. Will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution :

Just add the property white-space: normal; to the input so that the text centers well.

```html
<body>
    <style>

        input {
            flex-shrink: 1;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: black;
            --tw-border-opacity: 0;
            --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 0.5rem;

            height: 1.5rem/* 24px */;
            padding-left: 0.5rem/* 8px */;
            padding-right: 0.5rem/* 8px */;
            font-size: 0.75rem/* 12px */;
            line-height: 1rem/* 16px */;
            line-height: 1.625;

            white-space: normal; /* !!! */
        }

    </style>
    With pre tag : <br>
    
    <pre><input type="datetime-local"/></pre>
    
    Without pre tag :<br>
    
    <input type="datetime-local"/>
</body>
```